# My dropdown menu does not appear html css vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code, I have already tried to change the display: none to block. its seems to be there, but once I change it to none and try to toggle using .active in javascript it not appear. already done the .dropdown ul il:hover . ul but still not working.

```js
console.log("hellokkk");

document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",openMenu);

Function openMenu() {
    
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.header{
    min-height: 20em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #00afef;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-links{
    text-align: center;
    align-item: center;
    width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    background:#fff;
     display: block;
     margin: 0;
}
.nav-links ul li{
    
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-links ul li {
    
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
#dropdown {
    
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
}
#dropdown.active{
    
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->
    <title>Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500;700&display=swap rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">

    <nav>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <ul>
                <ul>
                <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li>
                <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;">Log Out</a></li>
                <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;">My Dashboard</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/9fx89Br.png" style="width:250px;height:100px;"></li>
                <li>Product</li>
                <li>Safety Tools</li>
                <li>Training</li>
                <li>Engagement</li>
                <li id="menu">Membership
                    <ul id="dropdown">
                            <li>Latest News</li>
                            <li>Subscribe to Newsletter</li>
                            <li>Videos</li>
                            <li>Publications</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li>News</li>
                <li>About</li>
            </ul>
                

</div>
</nav>

    <script src="header.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like my dropdown menu to appear when I clicked on the membership menu, can someone help me

Comment: How can help you without code

Comment: Can you please go into detail, what is your related code, what is the expected result, what is the actual result and what have you tried?

Comment: sorry, done re-edit

Comment: The `function` keyword has to be written with a lower f. `Function` with capital F is an object class.

Answer (score 1):

There's a single problem that you did in the function declaration of your js. You just need to change the capital 'F' to 'f' of the line of function in order to make the code work. Javascript is case sensitive language, so your code didn't worked as you used Function for declaring a function.

To make the dropdown list horizontal, you need to remove the position relative property from .nav-links ul li selector in the css and then to get those vertical lines you need to create .nav-links ul li ul li selector that will select the dropdown list and add border-left property to get those vertical lines. Also, in order to make those icons of social media visible, you need to add the fontawesome link in the head section of the html code. I am adding the whole code in the next answer. Please find it below.

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <!--<meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->
      <title>Header</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Montserrat:wght@300;500;700&display=swap rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }
  .header{
  min-height: 20em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00afef;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  }
  nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  }
  .nav-links{
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  background:#fff;
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-links ul li{

  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav-links ul li {

  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.2rem;

  /* position: relative; */
  }
  #dropdown {

  display: none;
  position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 999;
 left: 0;

  }
 .nav-links ul li ul li{
    border-left: 3px solid #000;

      }
      #dropdown.active{

      display:block;
  }</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">

<nav>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
            <ul>
            <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"> 
 </i></a></li>
            <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> 
 </a></li>
            <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> 
     </li>
            <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;">Log Out</a></li>
            <li><a href"" style="color:#00afef;">My Dashboard</a> 
       </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/9fx89Br.png" 
   style="width:250px;height:100px;"></li>
            <li>Product</li>
            <li>Safety Tools</li>
            <li>Training</li>
            <li>Engagement</li>
            <li id="menu">Membership
                <ul id="dropdown">
                        <li>Latest News</li>
                        <li>Subscribe to Newsletter</li>
                        <li>Videos</li>
                        <li>Publications</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        
            <li>News</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
        

</div>
</nav>
<script>console.log("hellokkk");

  document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",openMenu);

      function openMenu() {

  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("active");
  }</script>
<script src="header.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much, another problem i have is can i have the drop down menu content in horizontal instead of vertical and may i know is there a problem on why my "youtube", twitter and linked in icon on the left side of "Log out" does not appear?

here the image for reference https://imgur.com/TWlXbBn

Comment: To make the dropdown list horizontal, you need to remove the position relative property from .nav-links ul li selector in the css and then to get those vertical lines you need to create .nav-links ul li ul li selector that will select the dropdown list and add border-left property to get those vertical lines. Also, in order to make those icons of social media visible, you need to add the fontawesome link in the head section of the html code. I am adding the whole code in the next answer. Please find it below.